# Virtual Machine in QEMU/KVM does not recognize some shortcuts with the <Super> key

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, display-server

## Background

I am running Awesome WM inside my virtual machine. From Awesome WM's [guide](https://awesomewm.org/doc/api/documentation/07-my-first-awesome.md.html#):

> Mod4+h, Mod4+l, Mod4+Shift+h and Mod4+Shift+l to resize windows.

In which <Mod4> is synonymous with <Super> or the Windows button.

But the <Mod4+h> and <Mod4+l> combinations do not resize the windows as expected, while <Mod4+Shift+h> and <Mod4+Shift+l> does do something. So I went into my Fedora host's Gnome settings and removed the <Mod4+l>=lock screen shortcut, and now the VM registers "Mod4+h, Mod4+l, Mod4+Shift+h and Mod4+Shift+l" correctly. Then, I created the lock screen short cut once again, and the VM is still able to register all the above operations.

EDIT: After the reboot of the VM, the shortcuts don't work anymore.

## Questions

1. Why did removing the host lock screen shortcut make it work?
2. How to make it so that shortcuts are only registered in the VM when my mouse is captured inside the VM?

Thank you very much.

## System Specs

Host: Fedora 37 Silverblue, Gnome 43.2, Wayland
VM: QEMU/KVM, `virt-manager`, archlinux, Awesome WM, X Server